# Not centering input text in the middle of the screen when selecting it on mobile

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, mobile

Is there a way to not center the input text in the middle of the screen when you're selecting it on mobile? When it does that, you have to keeping scrolling up to read the text above it after you press enter, which is not good.

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>

//a div containing text from an ajax call after entering the input text
<input type = "text">
```

Comment: where do you want the text field to be on the screen ?

Comment: @DinoMyte Exactly where it was before it was selected.

Comment: not sure what you meant by that, could you create a fiddle of your code ?

Comment: @DinoMyte Better. I can just give you the link to my actual website where this is happening. www.chatwithibot.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use css to pull the text where you want it.

wrap the text in a div and then position it where you want it. That way your ajax shouldn't have any effect on where it ends up.

```
<div id="ajaxCall" class="fixText">
  Ajax call
</div>
```

attributes like the ones below help you move text around:

```
#ajaxCall{
  text-align: left;
  position: relative / absolute;
  margin-top / bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the way iOS moves the page's contents when the native keyboard is activated? If so you could try using JavaScript to mitigate. Consider listening for the input to gain focus and then adjust the scroll position of the page or a specific element. Something like:

```
$(function() {
     $(input).focus(function() {
          $(document).scrollTop(500);
     });
});
```

(uses jQuery)

Comment: Can I not just disable the IOS doing that instead of trying to estimate?

Comment: Also, I have no idea how to "listen for the input to gain focus"; so if you include the codes for that too, it would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: @jessica, in your case, it would be $("#lower input:text").focus(function() { $(document).scrollTop(500); });

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following via jquery `animate()` function. Here, the scroll location has been to `400` so you may need to change it based on your requirement.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{         
$("#lower input:text").focus(function()
{
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 400
    }, 2000);
});
});
```

Here's an example in action : http://jsfiddle.net/qggpjLqp/